# Add sound switch off/on button corona sdk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I need help with adding sound off/on button to my game. In global variable lua file, I have the following:

```
local sounds = {}
sounds["select"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/select.mp3")
sounds["score"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/score.mp3")
G.playSound = function(name) 
    if sounds[name] ~= nil then 
        audio.play(sounds[name])
    end
end
```

In games.lua file, I call the function as:

```
utils.playSound("score")
```

I have a soundon.png and soundoff.png files both in a sprite sheet (not sure if that is a good idea), all I am trying to implement is when you click the sound button, all sounds stops and it displays the soundoff image, vice versa.
Thanks

Comment: Complete your question by showing your code for button click, and explaining how are you trying to do what you want now. Please also check Rob's tutorial on code formatting: https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/06/09/tutorial-the-value-of-well-formatted-code/

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use a sprite sheet. Just load both images and toggle their "isVisible" field. Then toggle a variable which would stop your sounds. Try something like this.

```
myGlobalSoundToggle = true
local image = display.newImage("soundon.png")
local image2 = display.newImage("soundoff.png")
image2.isVisible = false

local function onTap( self, event )
    image.isVisible = ~image.isVisible
    image2.isVisible = ~image2.isVisible
    myGlobalSoundToggle = image.isVisible
    return true
end 
image:addEventListener( "tap", onTap )
```

Now that we have our buttons working, we need to toggle the sound on and off.

```
local sounds = {}
sounds["select"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/select.mp3")
sounds["score"] = audio.loadSound("sounds/score.mp3")
G.playSound = function(name) 
    if (sounds[name] ~= nil) and (myGlobalSoundToggle) then 
        audio.play(sounds[name])
    end
end
```